# C# - Cast instance to generic interface returns null

Tags: c#, oop, generics

I have the following method:

```
IResponseToModelConverter<U, IEntity> CreateConverter()
{ 
return new ResponseToItemConverter() as IResponseToModelConverter<U, IEntity>;
}
```

`ResponseToItemConverter` inherits from a base class that implements `IResponseToModelConverter`.
`Item` is type of `IEntity`, and I can get the type of `U`.
Is there a way for this to work?

Comment: If the ResponseToItemConverter doesn't implement this interface directly then no, you can't. There is no duck typing in C#.

Comment: It inherits from a base class that implements the interface. I forgot to mention that.

Comment: It will only return a non-null value if either `U` is a concrete type and `ResponseToItemConverter` happen to implement the interface `IResponseToModelConverter<U, IEntity>`, or in the cases where the generic type argument `U` is passed in as a type which the class implements the same interface for.

Comment: But you will have to post the class surrounding the method CreateConverter, as well as the interface and ResponseToItemConverter class to get a better answer.

Comment: @user6251216 No, it doesn't inherit from a base class that implements the interface. If it did, you wouldn't be asking this question, since you wouldn't be getting a `null` result. Perhaps the base class implements some other `IResponseToModelConverter<,>` instantiation, but not the one you're asking for.

Comment: Let's say     Result is type of    U. If I cast to     IResponseToModelConverter<Result, Item> it returns correctly. But I need to return    IResponseToModelConverter<U, IEntity> and that cast returns null...

Comment: @user6251216 `IResponseToModelConverter<Result, Item>` is different from `IResponseToModelConverter<Result, IEntity>`.

Comment: I know. That's why I asked how can I make this work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced     IEntity with type parameter     T (with IEntity constraint) so I can pass a concrete class when I cast to the interface. That solved my problem.